# how to open downloaded file after unzipping in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c

good morning. i used the following example to download and unzip a [file](http://www.touch-code-magazine.com/update-dynamically-your-iphone-app-with-new-content/#comment-8524) in my app.

normally my app calls an html file with the following code:

```
- (IBAction)loadLocalFile:(id)sender
{
    UIButton *tmp = sender;
    int tag = tmp.tag;
    NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"dossier%i", tag];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@""];
    NSString *filePath = @"";

    switch (tag) {
        case 1:
        {
            filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:fileName ofType:@"html"];
            break;
        }
        case 2:
        {
            filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:fileName ofType:@"html"];
            break;
        }
        case 3:
        {
            filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:fileName ofType:@"html"];
            break;
        }

        default:
            break;
    }

    url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];
    LocalViewController *vc = [[LocalViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LocalViewController"     bundle:nil url:url];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
}
```

how can I modify the above code so it looks in the `documentsDir` and if the unzipped file is there, open that one instead of the one in the app bundle.

Comment: You are aware that the switch stament does the same thing in all case, and that you can also call `URLForResource:withExtension:` and that you no longer need to convert the path to a `NSURL`. And what have you tried to open the zip file or even locate the document directory?

Comment: Don't you find it odd that you have a switch statement that does exactly the same thing for all but the default case?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set `filePath` with the path of the file of the name `fileName`, you can use something like the following:

```
NSString *documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)[0];
NSString *filePath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
```